# Word for the noise made by a knife

Tags: single-word-requests, sounds

[Bark](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yPkr1XQFNJA) is the abrupt, harsh, explosive cry of a dog.

[Clatter](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yHQePNrxsm8) is the sound made by two or more hard objects hitting each other.

[Splash](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YtQK38eyqKU) is the sound of something falling into a liquid, normally water.

What is the name of the sound made by a knife? And more in particular, is there a different name for the [sound of a knife slashing through the air](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0_OIkmarZek) and [the sound made by a knife hitting flesh](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XXLIECVCogc)?

Additional example:

> Blindfolded, I could only hear noises: the distant barking of a dog, the shouting of a terrified man, the [word] of a knife being waved into the air.

Comment: Eager to know myself. Waiting for an answer

Comment: [Snikt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wolverine:_Snikt!) is established in a very similar context. I'm thinking of the hitting flesh part of the question.

Comment: I know these are words, but... Aren't they just onomatopoeias that caught on? Of that is indeed the case, you can use whatever onomatopoeia you want.

Comment: _the whooshing of a knife being waved into the air_

Comment: Sorry, Edgar; a knife can't be "waved into the air" even though it could be waved "in" or "through" the air. If you really doubt the sound of anything slashing through the air or hitting flesh are different, why not ignore that unreal difference and use the same term for both?

In any case, what did your dictionaries, thesauruses or even search engines not say?

Could you try reading several books whose authors have already overcome this "problem"?

Comment: knives through the air do not make an audible sound.....and knives don't "hit" flesh unless thrown.

Comment: Blindfolded, I could only hear noises: the distant barking of a dog and shouting of a terrified man and never knew a knife was being waved around in the air.....

Comment: There are regularities that can be used. Most phonosemantic chunks have an audial aspect. For instance, most [_KL-_ words](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/kl-chart.pdf) refer to things being or moving together, and a subset of them has to do with the noises produced by such movement.

Answer (score 18):

There can't be a single word to describe so many different noises, or if there was such a word it wouldn't be very useful.

I suggest the ***swish*** of a knife through the air. Hitting a metal object (parried by another blade, or hitting armour or a shield) would be better served by ***clang***. If a knife struck a living body, the dominant noise would be the cry of pain; chopping at a dead body would be more of a ***thud*** or ***thwack*** (correct me if I'm wrong, I haven't tried this personally but it's just meat).

Also I wouldn't say "waved in*to* the air"; "waved through the air" or just about "in the air" would be better. "Into" would go more with "thrown" but then you wouldn't want to be there when it landed.

Answer (score 0):

**Swish**

OED:

> **A. adv. or int.**
>
> **Expressive of the sound made by the kind of movement defined in B. 1; with a swish. Also reduplicated swish, swish.**
>
> a1911   in ‘G. A. Birmingham’ Lighter Side Irish Life (1912) iv. 72   So the executioner swung his sword and swish went poor John's [the Baptist's] head.
>
> **B. n.1**
>
> **1. a. A hissing sound like that produced by a switch or similar slender object moved rapidly through the air or an object moving swiftly in contact with water; movement accompanied by such sound.**
>
> 1896   ‘I. Maclaren’ Kate Carnegie 289   In my study I hear the swish of the scythe.

And from Google Books:

> **Delphi Complete Works of A. E. W. Mason** 2019 *We heard the swish of the knife, the struggle of George Crottle to arrest him, the slamming of the door, and the key turned in the lock.*

> **Divided Loyalties** Nilofar Shidmehr • 2019 *Then, when the time comes — when the new haji approaches him, and his companions cheer in the name of Our Prophet Mohammad — the butcher cuts the sheep's head off with one quick swish of the knife.*

Answer (score -1):

As you said **slash** might be used when the knife swings through air. Two knives scratch against each other. So **scratch** can be used in the latter scenario.

Answer (score -1):

Tssik. If the knife is being thrown into a metal object. Not through. if you're throwing the knife through a metal object it would be more of a Ssoo-ik.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -4):

If you want a knife sound based on slicing a throat, you could use:

1. 'Slice!'
2. 'Slit!'
3. 'Crrrr!' (If your writing is informal, only)
4. 'Tss!'